# How are "handles" described in point set topology?

Tags: general-topology

I recently began learning about topology in terms of neighborhoods, open and closed sets, boundary and limit points. I'm trying to reconcile this with the view of topology as "rubber sheet geometry".

In particular, I'm picturing the set of points comprising the interior and boundary of a circle on the plane. If I understand correctly, this would be a closed set, <strike>and also an open set because the rest of the plane is closed</strike>.

From the rubber sheet view, I understand that the plane is pretty much like the surface of a sphere, and that if you add a "handle" to the sphere, you get a surface that's equivalent to a torus.

How do we express this "handle" concept in the language of point set topology?

Comment: You mean something like: 1) remove two discs from the sphere; 2) take the disjoint union with a cylinder; 3) take the quotient by the equivalence relation identifying boundaries of the cylinder with boundaries of the removed discs; 4) prove the resulting topological space is homeomorphic to the torus?

Comment: I'm talking about handles: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Handle_theory ... What you're saying sounds right, but I'm not looking for a proof, I'm just looking for what concepts or words in point set topology correspond to this idea...

Comment: For connected $2$-manifolds $X$, adding a "handle" means taking the connected sum with a torus. Since $X$ is connected, this will give the same result as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior of the circle together with its boundary is a closed set. It's not also open, because the "rest of the plane" isn't closed - it's open.

The plane isn't quite like the surface of a sphere. It is near any point, but on the plane you can find an infinite sequence of points that never cluster anywhere. On the surface of the sphere that's impossible. (Of course this depends on a precise definition of "cluster").

To talk rigorously about the handle concept you have to do a fair amount of work. You define paths as continuous functions from the circle (just the boundary) into the space. Then you make precise what it means to "shrink a path to a single point". Then you have a (kind of) handle when you have a path that can't shrink to a point.

Comment: Hrm, thanks for clearing up my mistakes. I can't tell if this answers my question or not. Like: I don't even see how the idea of a boundary or a closed set can apply to a circle on the plane if there's a handle sticking out of the middle and connecting it to the rest of the plane. It seems like there's no longer really an inside or an outside to it, so how can you even say it's bounded?

Comment: "Bounded" and "boundary" have the same root, but they are not related concepts topologically. In the plane, any set such that lies completely inside some circle is bounded. That has nothing to do with the boundary of a set. As my answer suggests, to understand point set topology takes some time - learning and getting used to the definitions and the theorems.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. "Inside a circle" makes sense on the plane or on the surface of a sphere, but "inside" no longer makes sense if the circle has a handle leading out over the boundary. So instead, you define a path around the circle, and define shrinking the path to point. Am I getting it now?

Comment: We are both still confused. "Inside a circle" does not make sense on a sphere. A handle "leading out over the boundary" doesn't make any sense to me. I think you just have to learn more formal topology - further back and forth here isn't going to help you.

Comment: If you have a sphere, you can draw a circle on it, and a point on the sphere is either "inside" or "outside" the circle. (It might not be clear which side is "inside", but a point is either on one side of the boundary or the other, so you can just pick one direction and call it "inward".) If you have a sphere with a handle on it, you can draw a circle around the handle, but it's no longer possible to say whether a given point is "inside" or "outside" the circle, because you can draw a path along the surface to the point in either the "inward" or "outward" direction.